# UIThread's Looper and Android app execution mechanism

Tags: android

What's happening when I launch an application,Touch the screen in between etc w.r.t UIThread,Looper

This is what I speculate.Please correct me

Every activity lifecycle method is put into uithread's looper by android and the UIthread execute those.For example:

User launched the application - android puts launcher activity's `onCreate()` in the queue and uithread executes it and similarly onStart() later.

And What's happening when user touches the screen,does android run 'user interface event loop' which puts respective event listener's method into the queue similarly??

Answer (score 0):

I think when an application is launched you can understand the activity life cycle on android developers website

[source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Regarding touch and event happening, UI all is written in Android OS whose yellow papers are not being released by Google. We can do is , we can perform action , modify the behavior of OS and many more.

Comment: Yeah I know about life cycle methods.My Question is whether those methods are being dispatched from the Looper Queue.Android developers guide doesn't tell anything about this

Comment: Okay tez I need some R&D time and would like to revert you ASAP